# Android - Simplest approach for a basic app? Details included

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I need to build a very simple Android app.  The app lists clients and within each client page, it lists their monthly progress reports.  Client information includes name, email, etc (Strings) and their progress report items includes a few more Strings.  My question is, what is the easiest approach to building something like this - The only task it really performs is adding new clients and adding progress items to each client.

The three ways I am aware of are:
- SQlite which seems pretty advanced
- XML 
- or SharedPreferences

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not shared preferences. XML would be OK, but for any such application data, Android seems to prefer you use SQLite. It's built-in, there are good tutorials, and it works well enough. That's really your easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is preferable. If you finally decide to use SQLite in your described case, but you don't want to dig into implementation too much, then you can use this eclipse plugin:

https://github.com/sromku/android-sqlite-model-generator-plugin

The plugin generates SQLite java source code for you, based on the schema you define by JSON file. The usage is very simple. For example, adding new Client in your case will be looked like:

```
// Define new client
Client client = new Client();
client.setName("John");
client.setEmail("email@some.com");
...

// Create and insert new client into database
Model model = Model.getInstance(context);
model.createClient(client);
```

All CRUD actions are supported.
So, for you question, I think that this is the easiest approach.

Hope it helped :)